# Ruby Slow Rendering on routing_error.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having trouble with my ruby server rendering this file very slowly. This is on a fresh rails install with no customized other than creating a "Hello World" welcome page. Could you help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

My routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'welcome#index'
end
```

My welcome#index:

```
<h1>Competitor's Tent</h1>
```

Please tell me if you need more info to help.

Edit: Server logs - https://hastebin.com/ezurunuhuh.vbs

Comment: Could you provide server logs, please?

Comment: In server logs its showing database specified `'mysql2' for database adapter` but gemfile is not added in your `Gemfile`, add `gem mysql2` in your `Gemfile`

Comment: If you look at the bottom of the posted logs you'll see that this issue (mysql2) has been remedied -- it's also not the issue I'm asking about. Thanks for the help though!